# Find a normal to a surface defined by $F(u,v) =0$, $u = xy$, $v = \sqrt{x^2+z^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, surfaces

This is a problem from Apostol, *Calculus, Volume II* (p. $302$, Chapter $9.8$).

> The three equations $F(u,v) = 0$, $u = xy$, and $v = \sqrt{x^2 + z^2}$ define a surface in $xyz$-space.  Find a normal vector to this surface at the point $x = y = 1, z = \sqrt{3}$ if it is known that $D_1F(1,2) = 1$ and $D_2 F(1,2) = 2$.

I think we would like to calculate $\partial F/\partial x$, $\partial F/\partial y$, $\partial F/\partial z$, then the normal is given by the function with these as its component functions and we can evaluate at $x=y=1$, $z = \sqrt{3}$.  First, we calculate

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} &= \frac{\partial F}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}
&&= y \frac{\partial F}{\partial u} + \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+z^2}}\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}\\
\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} &= \frac{\partial F}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} 
&&= x \frac{\partial F}{\partial u}\\
\frac{\partial F}{\partial z} &= \frac{\partial F}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial z} 
&&= \frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+z^2}}\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}
\end{align*}

From here, I do not know how to proceed.  The answer given in the book is

$$ 2\mathbf{i} + \mathbf{j} + \sqrt{3} \mathbf{k}. $$

Comment: Use Cross product

Comment: @Nameless In what way?  Cross what with what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the function $G:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ to be $G(x,y,z)=(u,v)=(u(x,y,z),v(x,y,z))$ and the function $H=F\circ G:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Since your surface is defined by $H=0$, the normal to this surface at any given point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is the vector $\nabla H(x_0,y_0,z_0)$. For example $\partial_x H$ is given by 
\begin{equation}
\partial_x H(x,y,z)=\partial_u F(u,v)\partial_xu(x,y,z)+\partial_v F(u,v)\partial_xv(x,y,z)
\end{equation}
as you calculated.
You have:
\begin{equation}
\partial_xu=y\qquad\partial_yu=x\qquad\partial_zu=0
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\partial_xv=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+z^2}}\qquad\partial_yv=0\qquad\partial_zv=\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+z^2}}
\end{equation}
At the point $(1,1,\sqrt{3})$ you get $u=1,v=2$; $\partial_xF(1,2)=1$ and $\partial_yF(1,2)=2$:
\begin{equation}
\partial_x H(1,1,\sqrt{3})=\partial_u F(1,2)\partial_xu(1,1,\sqrt{3})+\partial_v F(1,2)\partial_xv(1,1,\sqrt{3})
\end{equation}
which yelds
\begin{equation}
\partial_x H(1,1,\sqrt{3})=1\cdot\partial_xu(1,1,\sqrt{3})+2\cdot\partial_xv(1,1,\sqrt{3})\\=1\cdot 1 + 2\cdot\frac{1}{2}=2
\end{equation}
So the first component of your vector is $2$. The others are obtained in the same way.